# Create Azure db login from code raises SqlException

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to create a new database login for my Azure database server. It is working when using SQL Management Studio but not from C# code and I couldn't figure out what the problem is.

The Azure documentation [Manage Database Logins](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-US/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-logins/) shows how to do it:

```
-- first, connect to the master database
CREATE LOGIN login1 WITH password='<ProvidePassword>';
CREATE USER login1User FROM LOGIN login1;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'dbmanager', 'login1User';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'loginmanager', 'login1User';
```

Again - this works like a charme as long as I use SQL Management Studio. Now I want to do the same from code. Please take a look at my code:

```
// This is ConnectionString to master database.
// 'User ID' in this string is sa login created in Azure Portal.
var cs = "Server=tcp:XXX.database.windows.net,1433;Database=master;User ID=XXX@XXX;Password=XXX;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=240";

// SQL command
var command = "CREATE LOGIN testLogin WITH password = 'Test123!!!'";

// Execute command using cs
using (var context = new MyDataContext(cs))
{
    // works fine - I am connected to the master db
    context.Database.Connection.Open();

    // this line throws exception
    //   "CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'"
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command);
 }
```

As you can see I've tried it 1:1 like the doc says but it doesn't work. Doing the exact same thing in SQL Management Studio it just works. I've also tried good old *SqlConnection* to be sure it's not caused by Entity Framework but that doesn't change anything.

I don't know what's the difference maker here. Am I missing something? Any hints on this?

**EDIT1:**
Here is the exception.

Message:

```
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

Source:

```
.Net SqlClient Data Provider
```

StrackTrace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)
at System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)
at System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[] parameters)
```

Comment: can you add the exception please?

Comment: This article on MSDN might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx . It may be that the connection string you are using is only giving you access to a specific database (logins are created on the SQL Instance, which contains many databases including "master".) You may need a compound statement like `CREATE LOGIN AbolrousHazem 
    WITH PASSWORD = '340$Uuxwp7Mcxo7Khy';
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
CREATE USER AbolrousHazem FOR LOGIN AbolrousHazem;
GO `

Comment: Is the any Inner Exception from the exception thrown from your C# code?

Comment: @Jay; I've added the exception. There is no InnerException.

Comment: @NickT: Creating the user will be my 2nd goal. At first I want to create the login. As far As I know I can not use "USE" statement with Azure SQL Database.

Comment: @mmmato From my limited Azure experience I think they provide a powershell API for stuff like user management, since the database is using a brand new version of SQL. It may be a special case. You might consider creating a create user powershell script that you can execute from the application if this continues to give you trouble. Did you already try creating a stored procedure and executing it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stack trace, it looks like Entity Framework is trying to run migrations before running your SQL command. Because your connection string points to the master database (not your user database), the migrations are trying to create tables in master which you aren't allowed to do.

If you really need to create the new SQL login from your app code, one solution would be to have your main Entity Framework connection string point to your user database, and create a separate SqlConnection with your master database's connection string to do the CREATE LOGIN step.